# set value of custom input before alert popup

Tags: javascript, sweetalert, sweetalert2

```
swal2({
  title: 'Messages',
  html: '<textarea id="text_messages" class="inpz textar" oninput="set_messages()" ></textarea>'
})
```

the problem is I need to set the value of textarea when it popup so when it shows it should already have the value I tried onfocus event for the textarea is working but need to focus to show the value, and I tried 'preConfirm'but I think its only trigger before html code load any idea of what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Why don't you use the value attribute?

Comment: that's what I'm doing but where to call it

Comment: I mean like this `<textarea id="text_messages" value="something awesome" ... />`

Comment: i tried but not working i stored value on variable and i set on the value but didnt work

Comment: Make a code snippet and share it here

Comment: let  data  =  'some text'
    swal2({  
    title: 'Messages',
    html: `<textarea id="text_messages" class="inpz textar" oninput="set_messages()" value ="${data}"></textarea>`,
    
      
    
    })

Comment: Where is the js which have data declared ? Before HTML or after ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
swal({
  html: '<textarea id="text_messages" class="swal2-textarea" rows="5"></textarea>',
  onOpen: function () {
    swal.getPopup().querySelector('#text_messages').value = 'custom value'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7"></script>
```

Comment: thanks its work perfectly and thanks for the amazing job on the project

Comment: Depending on a scenario I would suggest not to use ids. Sweetalert may be used to instantiate multiple popups at once.